# Installation of home-assistant-supervised for macOS

Tags: home-assistant

I was wondering if anybody knows if it's possible to install a home assistant with docker to the Mac without virtual machines. I've found this topic and it worked for the basic version of home assistant:

https://www.phatpenguin.com/2018/12/hassio-via-docker-on-mac.html?showComment=1635791899259#c6940582515373249537

But I need a supervised version and I can't find if there is the same way, but with a different docker image.

Answer (score 0):

After a month of trying, I could not get a supervised version installed with Docker on my Mac either.  Proxmox wasn't an option.

I went with the [officially supported](https://www.home-assistant.io/installation/macos) [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) install and couldn't be more pleased.  It didn't slow down the 8GB of ram on my 2011 Mac Mini, and all of the supervised features work great.

Comment: I wish I knew how you did that. I followed their instructions to the letter, and I mean, TO THE LETTER, from the page you linked. I checked sentence-by-sentence repeatedly to try and catch something I'd misread. And the image just doesn't work on my 2012 MBP with Mojave. `Failed to open a session for the virtual machine homeassistant. Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-en0' (VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND). Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND).`